# Jingle (Music) in an app

Tags: app, music

I want to know different approaches for using jingles inside an App. I want to create a non-entertainment app that uses one of the jingles of the company. But I'm out of ideas on how to include it.

It's a Taxi-like app, when the driver is near to you the app will play a car-horn like sound when you open the app we want it to sound a music similar to the one you listen when you are waiting for an elevator.

I was thinking that at the moment the app loads for the first time, play the jingle and that's it, this will be played only when you start the app.

What are your opinions?

Comment: No. Don't do it.

Comment: As to whether or not to use it, that depends on LOTS of factors. Here's a few, but I'm sure there's more:

 1. Company's image. If they're a highly professional accounting firm, probably not. If they're a trendy techie startup, maybe.
 2. User's expectation. Don't make them jump.
 3. Typical environment. Where are your users going to be using this app? If it's in the office, no.

Comment: @aljndrrr: *Why* do you want to play the music though? Have you had user feedback stating 'Ooh this app is too boring and quiet so I don't bother using it'? Is the business trying to link the jingle to some advertising campaign? Or is it just "We think it might be cool to play some music here"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to playing MIDI's on a website back in the 90's. Just don't do it. It wont add anything.

Now, if you're doing it to alert the user when a cab is nearby, then it MIGHT be a good idea. However, it sounds like their marketing people think it's a cool feature. It's not. Don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

First launch, novelty.

Subsequent launches, irritation.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely be careful about how sound/audio is used in the app. There are some implications such as how it links to your brand image and whether it is a key element or not that you have to weigh up against things like if it will disrupt something that the user is doing or annoy them (if there are no options to switch it off without turning the sound to mute).

The period of time that you play it is also important, because it will then hold up the time for loading the app, or cut into when they are doing something. The best way is to test and get reaction from the user, but make sure that it is something that they would not mind have playing all the time, otherwise I would probably not consider implementing it.